# How to avoid redundancy when creating a FK to a class that has a constraint based on a field of a source class

Tags: python, class, django-orm

I'm relatively new to programming, so this question may be pointless (it seems to be a common problem and I've tried to google it, but I've failed to find an answer), sorry for that...

I use Django, so suppose I have two model classes:

```
class SomeClass1(models.Model):
    some_type = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=2)
    object1_value = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class SomeClass2(models.Model):  
    some_class1 = models.ForeignKey(SomeClass1, blank=True, null=True)
    some_type = models.CharField(choices=CHOICES, max_length=2)
    object2_value = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Both of them have 'some_type' field: the SomeClass2 has this field, because it's its natural attribute, and the SomeClass1 has the field to restrict choice for 'some_class1' field when creating an object of SomeClass2.

This is the simplest example, but I have a bunch of these with some alterations. In this concrete example 'some_type' of SomeClass1 can't be used for SomeClass2, because 'some_class1' FK is optional, but presence of 'some_type' in SomeClass2 is mandatory.

Comment: _"SomeClass1 has the field to restrict choice for 'some_class1' field when creating an object of SomeClass2"_ - can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve here? What do the two "some_type" fields have in common and why are they related?

Comment: For example: SomeClass1 is a Dialect, SomeClass2 is a Text and CHOICES is a list of languages. When creating a Text, a language must be set, but a dialect is optional. On second thoughts I've understood that it is not a redundancy problem, but an integrity. Some my question transforms to: is it possible to design classes in a way so it is impossible to create an object of SomeClass2, that have some_type, different to that of an object of SomeClass1, to which the former has a FK?